# JQ how to print newline and not newline character from json value

Tags: json, newline, jq

I have some logs that output information in JSON. This is for collection to elasticsearch.

Some testers and operations people want to be able to read logs on the servers.

Here is some example JSON:

```
{
"@timestamp": "2015-09-22T10:54:35.449+02:00",
"@version": 1,
"HOSTNAME": "server1.example",
"level": "WARN",
"level_value": 30000,
"logger_name": "server1.example.adapter",
"message": "message"
"stack_trace": "ERROR LALALLA\nERROR INFO NANANAN\nSOME MORE ERROR INFO\nBABABABABABBA BABABABA ABABBABAA BABABABAB\n"
}
```

And so on.

Is it possible to make Jq print newline instead of the \n character sequence as seen in the value of `.stack_trace`?

Comment: I initially searched for "json logs prettyprint" but this didn't show up until I added jq to the search query (web search). Thanks anyway for the useful questions/answers, I just which I'd found this easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input as originally given isn't quite valid JSON, and it's not clear precisely what the desired output is, but the following might be of interest.  It is written for the current version of jq (version 1.5) but could easily be adapted for jq 1.4:

```
def json2qjson:
  def pp: if type == "string" then "\"\(.)\""  else . end;
  . as $in
  | foreach keys[] as $k (null; null; "\"\($k)\": \($in[$k] | pp)" ) ;


def data: {
  "@timestamp": "2015-09-22T10:54:35.449+02:00",
  "@version": 1,
  "HOSTNAME": "server1.example",
  "level": "WARN",
  "level_value": 30000,
  "logger_name": "server1.example.adapter",
  "message": "message",
  "stack_trace": "ERROR LALALLA\nERROR INFO NANANAN\nSOME MORE ERROR INFO\nBABABABABABBA BABABABA ABABBABAA BABABABAB\n"
};

data | json2qjson
```

Output:

```
$ jq -rnf json2qjson.jq
"@timestamp": "2015-09-22T10:54:35.449+02:00"
"@version": 1
"HOSTNAME": "server1.example"
"level": "WARN"
"level_value": 30000
"logger_name": "server1.example.adapter"
"message": "message"
"stack_trace": "ERROR LALALLA
ERROR INFO NANANAN
SOME MORE ERROR INFO
BABABABABABBA BABABABA ABABBABAA BABABABAB
"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this information. What I want is to be able to tail, cat, head, printf (or whatever), a logfile and get the output with newlines and not \n in the stack_trace value.

Comment: jigong - You can do all those things by using json2qjson, but it all depends on the exact nature of the input. Do you have  a stream of JSON objects or an array?  If the former, do they conform to the jsonlines convention? Also, since jq does not have a command-line option for *head* or *tail*, you'll have to program that in jq yourself, unless the input follows the jsonlines convention.  In short, your problem statement is insufficient to give further specific details.

Comment: If you're on jq 1.4 (version avail. in current Ubuntu ATM), you can use `sed` instead (see my answer for details).

Answer (score 83):

Sure! Using the `-r` option, jq will print string contents directly to the terminal instead of as JSON escaped strings.

```
jq -r '.stack_trace'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Is it possible to print everything else as normal and only use -r for the stack_trace value? jq -r '.stack_trace' will only print the stack_trace and not the rest of the information.

Comment: Well, jq always outputs valid JSON elements unless if given strings on `-r`. You could do some weird string conversion for the object, but you probably don't want to do that. What is the purpose of this conversion? It feels like this is unlikely to be the right approach for whatever problem you aim to solve.

Answer (score 20):

Unless you're constraint to use `jq` *only*, you can "fix" (or actually "un-json-ify") `jq` output with `sed`:

```
cat the-input | jq . | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

If you happen to have tabs in the input as well (`\t` in JSON), then:

```
cat the-input | jq . | sed 's/\\n/\n/g; s/\\t/\t/g'
```

This would be especially handy if your `stack_trace` was generated by Java (you didn't tell what is the source of the logs), as the Java stacktrace lines begin with `<tab>at<space>`.

Warning: naturally, this is not *correct*, in a sense that JSON input containing `\\n` will result in a "" output, however it should result in "n" output. While not correct, it's certainly sufficient for peeking at the data by humans. The `sed` patterns can be further improved to take care for this (at the cost of readability).

Comment: Is there a way to have `sed` preserve the color/bold formatting from `jq`?

Comment: Figured it out: `jq` does not seem to color its output when piping the results. To force `jq` to color its output use the `-C` flag.